# How to use FMS with C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash-media-server

I actually need a way to work with a Flash media Server using c# and asp.net.

And I don't have a clue about how to accomplish that I've been looking for documentation but haven't found anything worth so far.

Thx in advance.

Edit: 
    What I want is to edit a Shared Object in FMS from Asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You mean consuming/publish videos between a web page and FMS? In that case the flash object communicates directly with FMS, it makes no difference if your web app is asp.net, php, ruby, etc

Comment: The same applies for shared objects, the flash component communicates directly to FMS. If you need a server to server communication (asp.net->fms) then you need a RTMP implementation for .net, not sure if there's an opensource one. You could always make your own, but it wont be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Flash front end, you could use a Flash WebService or HTTPService to communicate with the .Net back end, and send the data retrieved from .Net into FMS via the Flash NetConnection.

It would help to know the specifics of what you're trying to do.

I've been working on a Flash/.Net/FMS app for a few months now, so can help out if you need any info.

Evan